# How can I improve ClickHouse server's startup time?

Tags: clickhouse

I am evaluating ClickHouse's performance for potential use in a project. The write performance has been encouraging up to this point but as I was running my tests and had to restart the server a few times, I noticed an issue which has the potential of being a hard showstopper: the server startup time is fluctuating and most of the times extremely high.

My evaluation server contains 26 databases holding about 54 billion records and taking up 697.32 GB on disk.

With this amount of data I have been getting startup times from as low as 7m35s to almost 3h.

Is this normal? Can it be solved with some fancier configuration? Am I doing something really wrong? Because, as it stands, such a long startup time is a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of slow startup time is due to the gigantic amount of metadata needed to be loaded, which has a positive correlation with the number of data files. In order to boost startup time, you need to either shrink the file count or get more memory in order to preserve all dentry and inode caches.

> My evaluation server contains 26 databases holding about 54 billion records and taking up 697.32 GB on disk.

I'd suggest the following:

1. Try adjustint current data partition schemes in a coarser manner
2. Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE <table> FINAL` to compact all data files
3. Upgrade data disk to SSD or efficient RAID, or use file systems like btrfs to store meta data separately on fast storage.

Comment: The schema is already as small as it can get. If this would go intro production, the whole thing would be more complicated and would hold a far larger amount of data. Using OPTIMIZE: "Although you can run an unscheduled merge using the OPTIMIZE query, don't count on using it, because the OPTIMIZE query will read and write a large amount of data." (from the official ClickHouse documentation https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replacingmergetree/ ). Finally, upgrading to a faster disk is not a solution. A server containing the same data in InfluxDB starts in 1s at most.

Comment: Then there is no much else to do. https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Storages/MergeTree/MergeTreeDataPart.cpp#L477   . ClickHouse reads multiple files for each data part upon starting, which are all random reads to the underlying disk. And since startup speed isn't of high priority, I don't see potential efforts of optimizing this process in near future.